# Bitcoin core balance won't show up!

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-wallet-app, bitcoin-foundation

I have bitcoin core wallet i havent use since 2013. i let it sync fully now but it won't show my bitcoin balance and this shows up.....

Warning: Unknown block versions being mined! It's possible unknown rules are in effect.

can someone tell me what do to do?

Comment: you need to upgrade your node by downloading the latest software. But that might not have anything to do with your balance being zero.